# Low API support Android

Tags: android, class, cordova, bluetooth, loading

We are working on a project that needs to support a range of devices.

For devices above api level 18 there must be Bluetooth LE support, making use of the BluetoothAdaptor class.

Now comes the problem, since it's imported from a cordova plugin our app crashes on boot on low api devices.

So now we are looking for a way to use the class, without loading it beforehand.

So we check for api level, if it is supported we want to load the class.

Is there a way? We heard about dynamic class loading, is this the way?

Comment: But you have to check `BluetoothAdaptor!=null` then load all the classes otherwise display some Toast msg... and if the device is `<18` then `BluetoothAdaptor==null` always .

Comment: The problem is that the classes get loaded immediately (even without specifying an import and using class directly) so it crashes out with the message that BluetoothAdapter is not available. We want the class to load only when api level is >=18

Comment: Wait, are you trying to use [BLE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) on devices with API<18? BLE was introduced since Android 4.3(API 18), so I don't think you can actually use it on lower-api devices

Comment: The Play Store will block installs on inappropriate devices. Makes sure the manifest file is correct.

Answer (score 0):

use null safe for this according to me. for device older(<18) class **BLE** and else **BluetoothAdaptor** .
Bluetooth = Bluetooth! BLE ? BluetoothAdaptor;